# How to execute a filter in the return clause of a cypher query in the .net Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4jclient

I'm having trouble figuring out how to put a filter in the return clause using the cypher linq Return function in the neo4j client.

I'm trying to do a query like this:

```
START Parents = node:app_fulltext('name:"City"'),
 MATCH Parents-[?:ChildOf]-Apps 
 WITH collect(Apps.Title) as myapps, collect(Parents.Name) as myparents
 RETURN myapps, filter(x in parents : not x in myapps) as myfilteredparents
```

I've tried starting with a with clause like this

```
.With("collect(Apps.Title) as myapps, collect(Parents.Name) as myparents")
.Return("myapps, filter(x in parents : not x in myapps) as myfilteredparents")
```

but I can't pass in a string to the Return method, and if I try to pass in some sort of filter into the LINQ lambda I get a `The return expression that you have provided uses methods other than those defined by ICypherResultItem.` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, complex return expressions with multiple identities are a bit icky in Neo4jClient. I'm open to ideas about how to support them nicely. The syntax is the hard part.

This is on the right track:

```
.With("myapps, filter(x in parents : not x in myapps) as myfilteredparents")
.Return("myapps, filter(x in parents : not x in myapps) as myfilteredparents")
```

However you're applying the filter twice: once in the `WITH`, then again in the `RETURN`.

Use the `WITH` clause to flatten it to simple identities (`myapps`, `myfilteredparents`) then `RETURN` those.

This code is untested, and typed straight into the answer window, but kind of what you want:

```
.With("myapps, filter(x in parents : not x in myapps) as myfilteredparents")
.Return((myapps, myfilteredparents) => new
{
    Apps = myapps.As<IEnumerable<string>>(),
    Parents = myfilteredparents.As<IEnumerable<Node<City>>>()
})
```

The `With` call shapes the data into a simple result set. The `Return` call describes the structure to deserialize this into.

Comment: doh sorry, copy and paste error in my question, I had the right with clause in my code, but the As<IEnumerable> part pointed me in the right direction